# Multiple file upload using custom directive in Angular

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular-reactive-forms, directive, custom-directive

I am trying to create a custom directive to validate multiple file upload.But in custom Directive, control is just returning the last file's details instead of array.

Below is the code :

File-upload.html :

```
<form [formGroup]="validateDocumentForm">
<input formControlName="document"  style="display: none" type="file" multiple (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput accept="application/pdf"  class="form-control">
<button class="btn upload-doc-btn" (click)="fileInput.click()"><span><i class="material-icons">vertical_align_top</i> Upload File</span></button>
```

file-upload.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
this.validateDocumentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  document: this.formBuilder.array(['', [
    CustomValidator.uploadDocument
  ]]),
});
```

}

Custom-validator.ts:

```
export class CustomValidator {
    static uploadDocument(control: AbstractControl): 
    ValidationErrors | null {
      console.log(control); // only last file's details instead of 
                               array of selected files.
      console.log(control.value);
      return  null;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the question wether you can implement a CustomValidator inside a seperate file I found this tutorial:
https://dev.to/angular/implement-file-upload-with-firebase-storage-in-our-angular-app-the-simple-way-1ofi

Basicly you are binding a method as a validator inside the component holding your form and this calls a seperate method in your validation file.

I hope this late answer could help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you should not use the formArray for the file upload. If you are using the formArray, you have iterate in the loop in the html file.([FormArray](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#dynamic-controls-using-form-arrays))

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.validateDocumentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'document':[''] 
    })
})
```

Selected files it won't be available in the `value` instead you have to use the `files` from the target.

```
onFileChanged(event) {
    for (const x of event.target.files) {
        console.log(x);
        // do the validation here
    }
}
```

Try to do the validation inside the component file not in the custom.validator file

**EDIT**

We have to store the files in the formcontrol so you can do something like this, in the component file

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.validateDocumentForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'document':['', uploadDocument] 
    })
})

onFileChanged(event) {
    this.validateDocumentForm['controls']['document']['files'] = event.target.files;
}
```

and in the custom.validators file

```
export function uploadDocument(c: AbstractControl) {
    console.log(c);
if (c['target'] && 'files' in c['target']) {
    for (const x of c['target'].files) {
        if (/*do your condition*/) {
            return {
                'fileNotValid': true
            };
        }
    }
 }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for answering . :) Is there any way that validation can be managed in custom.validator file only, instead of using the component file?